# MySQL: how to delegate alias into subquery of subquery?

Tags: mysql, delegates, nested, subquery, alias

How can I delegate my DV_ID or DV.ID into the second (deeper) subquery? Is it possible? (If I'd have just one level of nesting it would work.)

```
SELECT DV.ID DV_ID, (
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * MYTABLE VSV
WHERE VSV.ID = DV_ID //DV_ID is not seen...
GROUP BY VSV.ID) A ) B
FROM MYTABLE2 DV
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use an alias in SELECT field list is not seen in the subquery. You can use DV.ID (DV is alias of your table).

In your example:

```
SELECT DV.ID DV_ID
```

you can replace your output alias with a string, like this:

```
SELECT DV.ID "Hi my dear"
```

but is not correct read that information inside other part of query

Comment: DV.ID is also not seen, only if nesting has one level. I'll update the question

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your particular query as:

```
SELECT DV.ID as DV_ID,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT VSV.ID)
        FROM MYTABLE VSV
        WHERE VSV.ID = DV.ID //DV_ID is not seen...
       ) as B
FROM MYTABLE2 DV;
```

(NOTE:  If `VSV.ID` can take on `NULL` values, the expression would be `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT vsv.ID) + MAX(vsv.id is null)` ).

Comment: Cool!!! You have recognized and solved my particular problem. Although this was not the original question, so not sure is it correct if I accept the answer in such case?